# Script error while using deploy.ps1 to deploy virtocommerce project

Tags: powershell, azure, deployment, e-commerce, virtocommerce

[image]I'm using the official virtocommerce azure deploy script under folder "virtocommerce\src\Extensions\Setup\VirtoCommerce.PowerShell" to deploy virtocommerce(with azure tool v2.4), i encounted some problems while running "deploy.ps1" script in windows azure powershell

1. In "azure-db.ps1", there's lot of syntax like "Get-Date –f" , the dash character is wrong ,"–" must be "-", otherwise you will get error.
2. In "azure-deploy.ps1", there's a function "build-search" which use cspack.exe to create "ElasticSearch.cspkg",that's correct, but for other packages such as "CommerceSite.cspkg" and "AzureScheduler.cspkg", i did not found any functions to create those packages, this will lead to an error says "CommerceSite.cspkg" can not be found.

Does anybody has the same problems?

Answer (score 1):

Turn out that there's some problem inside code:

1. "deploy.ps1" script is using deploy-tfs.ps1 , and use parameter "$build".
2. parameter "$build" has been reset to 'False' in "deploy-tfs.ps1"
3. "azure-deploy.ps1" using "$build" to decide if it's need to build the azure package, and this parameter is always 'False', so the azure package will never be creat.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Parameter is not always false, it is false if parameter is not passed to a script.

Comment: @Woland, parameter "$build" not working in deploy.ps1 even if you set to True,  i guess you are using TFS as CI deployment , so yon don't have this problem, could you please try to download a new source package, and try to only run the  "deploy.ps1", then you will see all problems

Comment: we don't use TFS, we actually use jenkins and it simply executes deploy-tfs.ps1, passing "–build "True"" as one of the parameter which causes the build to execute. It uses the latest build scripts as it downloads them directly from github repository. No problems with master or webadmin branches.

Answer (score 0):

The script is designed to run on azure sdk 2.4, not 2.5. The script is used to deploy daily both demo and testing environments and were completed succesfully today. You can see the status here: https://virtocommerce.codeplex.com.

As for cspkg, it is generated during actual build, by msbuild. The elastic search ccspkg has to be created differently, as it has to include javaruntime in addition to elasticsearch runtime and packaged into a single setup.

The new, 1.13 version of Virto Commerce by default deploys azure website instead of azure cloud service for website and scheduler (deployed as a web job). Only elastic search is deployed as a cloud service. The setting can be changed in deploy.ps1.

Also make sure to check the complete instructions on how to deploy source code to azure at http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc1devguide/Source+Code+Azure+Deployment.

Comment: thanks, but i suggest to upgrade the script to run on sdk 2.5, as it's been release for 3 month, lots of people are now using sdk2.5

Comment: i changed to use sdk 2.4, still has this problem, please see my screenshot

Comment: As you mentioned build doesn't run, the build = "True" should be set in deploy.ps1 file.